# Faster alternative to L.geoJson() / removeLayer() in Mapbox?

Tags: mapbox

I have two very large geojson layers (~3000 shapes each) that I toddle between in my web app. It takes about 5-6 seconds to do a `map.removeLayer(); L.geoJson();` on the two layers. Is there any way I can hide the layers? Is there a faster format to load than geoJson?

Answer (score 1):

Try playing around with [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson), which depending on your data, can shrink your data substantially, which might help some with load times.  Additionally, if your data consists only of densely clustered points, using the [leaflet cluster plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) lightens the load on what your browser has to render.

But ultimately, if you're dealing with large datasets, it makes the most sense to tile the data out ahead of time, using a tool like [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) or [MapBox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/#darwin).  Rendering vectors directly in the browser can't really scale above small/medium-sized datasets.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try those things.